# Using an executable inside a gradle junit test

Tags: testing, gradle, junit, binary, executable

I have a binary that I want to use in my test. I want to put this binary in the test/resources folder so that anyone who loads the project and runs the test will have access to the binary and the test will be able to run without any extra configurations. My issue is, the test is run via a gradle task and I can't find any info on how to get gradle to see the binary in a way that lets the test use it.

I'm calling the binary in the test using

```
String command = "cf";  
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command, null, null);
```

The cf executable is located inside the test/resources folder.

As is, I get the error: Cannot run program "cf": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: It might if you provide more information, for example the actual code you're running including how you're looking up the path for your binary and what error you're getting

Comment: I added some more info. There's not much code other than trying to run the executable in the test/resources folder. I'm not sure where to start to add or reach that path [via gradle].

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `command` will be looking in the CWD for the file `cf`.  You need to locate it via the classloader, like this:

```
String command = getClass().getResource("cf").getFile();
```

This will give you an absolute path to the executable.